# How to use a google apps script in multiple documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that I want to use in multiple documents. I also may want to change it later in those documents, so it is imperative that I use the *same* script in all those documents, and not copies of that script.

I am aware of the below question, which may qualify as a duplicate, but I am reluctant to accept its answer.

[Google Apps Script - How To Have One Script In multiple containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814030/google-apps-script-how-to-have-one-script-in-multiple-containers)

So, my question is: is there really no way to *share* a script among multiple google documents? Must you really create a new script project for every document and copy-and-paste the code from an other? Moreover, if you fix a bug in one of them, do you have to remember which documents use that script and open the script editor in each of them and copy-and-paste the new code?

Answer (score 7):

Libraries were designed specifically for this situation... please have a look at the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).

Comment: This is somewhat useful, as it kind-of solves my second concern (i.e. how do you propagate a bugfix), except that is does not solve it as far as I see, as you have to select a specific version of the library, so you must still walk each of your files and select the new version if you updated your library. This may be a little less error prone than copying-and-pasting but still vulnerable to omission (i.e. forgetting to update in all documents). The solution maybe is to create a wrapper library that rarely changes, but alas, you have to jump hoops again to solve a simple problem...

Comment: Also, libraries do not solve the first problem: having to create a new script project and copying-pasting code for each document (they actually make things a little harder, as you have to include a library _and_ copy-paste some code that uses that library, albeit allowing for some slightly easier maintainability).

Comment: note that you can use the "development mode" that does not need to change version and uses the latest saved version. About your other concern, the ideal situation is to create each doc with the included necessary "skeleton" that calls the library from the beginning(using templates). If your docs already exist then is will indeed be a bit more tedious.

Comment: Now I see that there is a "developer mode" option that follows a library's latest version if the receiver has edit access to the library, so my first concern seems to be less serious. Still, having to give write access so that the user can have the latest changes is somewhat interesting.

Comment: I found that using a library doesn't work for the cases where this would be most useful, such as the onOpen function to create a sidebar.  What happens is that functions being called by the HTML Service are not properly resolved into the scope of the library itself, resulting in "function not found" errors.  I have even tried hacking around it by fully qualifying the function calls but that did not work either.

Answer (score 4):

As of September 6, 2020, using a library implies to create a project to add the reference to the library and some code to make the library functions available to the container document. The only way to have a script available on multiple documents without having to create an script on them and without limitations is by creating a **G Suite Editor add-on**.

As of December 2019 all the G Suite editor add-ons are published to the G Suite Marketplace. You could make an add-on unlisted and only users having G Suite accounts could published add-ons limited to be visible by other users from the same domain.

#### Test as add-on

If you don't want to publish and add-on you might use the Run > Test as add-on but there are several limitations. I.E. the following can't be used on this mode:

- Triggers
- Custom Functions

#### Master project

As suggested on [Giussepes' answer](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons), is to use a "master project" to hold your scripts. This also has several limitations

- Most of the active methods can't be used
- Simple triggers can't be used but it's possible to programatically create installable triggers
- Custom functions only works on spreadsheets add-ons and scripts bounded to the spreadsheet that will use the custom function

#### Be resigned

If you are resigned to have a project on each of your documents you could reduce the burden of keeping the scripts updated by using CLASP or the [Goole Apps Script Assistant for GitHub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en)

Resources

- [Builting editor add-ons | G Suite](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons)
- [Command line interface using clasp | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)

Answer (score 3):

I have come up with a solution that works for me. It allows keeping any number of scripts attached to a sort of master document (let's call it MyScripts). No libraries, no publishing required.

Create a document and name it MyScripts (or whatever). The document's body can be empty, or you could write some instructions there. Then, paste the following code into MyScript's script editor:

```
// adds a menu to the master document's UI
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
             .createAddonMenu()
             .addItem('Do something', 'doSomething')
             .addItem('Something else', 'somethingElse')
             .addToUi()
}

// returns the target document based on its URL
// may be tweaked in order to use the documentId instead
function findDoc(prompt) {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var pro = ui.prompt(prompt, 'Document URL:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var url = pro.getResponseText();
  return DocumentApp.openByUrl(url);
}

function doSomething() {
  var doc = findDoc('Do something');
  if (doc) {
    // do something with the target document
    var len = doc.getBody().getText().length;
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('The document is ' + len + ' characters long')
  }
}

function somethingElse() {
  var doc = findDoc('Something else');
  if (doc) {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

The `onOpen()` function should be self explanatory.

`findDoc()` is the real hack. It prompts the user for the URL of the target document, the document we want to act on. If the URL is valid, then `findDoc()` returns the corresponding document object.

The last two functions are just stubs and should be replaced with your own code, but notice how `findDoc()` gets called at the beginning of each.

When you want to run a script against a document, copy its URL, then open MyScripts, choose the corresponding Add-Ons menu item, paste the URL and click OK.

Please notice that you will get a scary warning message the first time you attempt to run a script this way. Just be sure that your `doSomething()`, your `somethingElse()`, etc. only contain safe code before ignoring the warnings and executing the scripts.

Comment: An alternative is to write a webapp which uses the Google Drive file picker: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

Comment: Hey, sounds like a good solution for my case too. Converting this to SpreadsheetApp i get the error on line 13 "ui is not defined" 

.prompt(pros, 'URL:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

Should this be tweaked to work with spreadsheets somehow?

Comment: JJxyz, it was a bug as pointed out by @user3264007. Should be fixed now

Comment: Tks. However this method only allows you to run macros against a specific document. What if we want to call functions in the Master Script file, while we are in a specific file?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my reputation was too low to add a comment. :(
In Giuseppe's answer use this for find docs - minor change

```
function findDoc(pros) {
  var ui =  DocumentApp.getUi();
  var pro = ui.prompt(pros, 'URL:', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var url = pro.getResponseText();
  return DocumentApp.openByUrl(url);
}
```