# Add a google apps script to a document using an apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a variation of this queastion (to which the answer seems to be "not possible"):
[How to use a google apps script in multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892753/how-to-use-a-google-apps-script-in-multiple-documents)

Is it possible to add an apps script (script A) to a document (document A) using a separate apps script (script B)?

If that's possible, it provides a partial solution to the above problem.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to edit the Script project of a document with another script. You have [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app) but I cannot find any methods to bind the script to any documents or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The closest that you're going to get is being able to perform code on multiple documents based on a trigger of a single source.

For example, you can have your script contained in a Google Sheet file and when something occurs, even time passing, it will trigger and will run through all other files. There could be a work-around that you have a conditional statement check something in your documents and if it matches, run that code block.

Here's a scenario -

1. 5 minutes passes -- begin code
2. code checks document 1 for condition -- condition met
3. code is performed on document 1
4. code checks document 2 for condition -- condition not met
5. code checks document 3 for condition -- condition met
6. code is performed on document 3
7. code completes

This would require an installed trigger, many, *many* if statements and some regiment to how those documents are read/ checked. It could also include a for loop in which you pull in an array of those documents and loop through each object, checking for the conditions you would have used to trigger those codes.

**TL;DR** You can't add code to another container, but you can pull multiple files into a single container, modify them with the code you intended for them, and save that new state.